# WPF, Caliburn.micro : How to bind property outside of current binding context?

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro

```
<DataTemplate>
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}"></TextBlock>
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Value}" SelectedItem="{Binging SomeProperty}">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
</StackPanel>
```

I am inside a Dictionary , I want to bind `SelectedItem="{Binging SomeProperty}"` SomeProperty is a property of the ViweModel, not inside of the Dictionary. How to do that? How can I bind to properties outside of current binding context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of `Binding` to the `Window.DataContext`'s property, you may do it the following way with `RelativeSource`:

```xaml
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Value}" SelectedItem="{Binding DataContext.SomeProperty, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}">
```

Or in case you want to display `SelectedItem` for example in some `TextBox` (for example collection of `string`):

```xaml
<TextBox Text="{Binding MyCollection/}"/>
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
```

`MyCollection` with "/" gets the current item of the `ICollectionView` used as `DefaultView` for `MyCollection`. [Read more >>>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop-wpf/data/data-binding-overview#collection-views)